How to create a formula that can a start date, frequency and dollar amount and output month summaries?
I'm trying to create a Google Sheets formula that can take a table of bills such as the below:



Start Date
Frequency
Amount




7/3/22
Monthly
$11.99


9/5/23
Quarterly
$109.00


11/9/23
Annually
$1100



And output into a summarised table such as the below:



Month
Amount




April 2024
$103.22


May 2024
$2109


June 2024
$343


July 2024
$210



The aim is to build a bill tracker that can take inputs such as the above, and show the required cashflow against each month over the coming 12 months.
I have tried to do this but I'm failing, here is my current formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
    {
      ARRAYFORMULA(
        FLATTEN(
          IF(
            B2:B="",,
            IF(
              E2:E="Weekly",
              TEXT(
                EDATE(
                  DATE(
                    YEAR(B2:B), 
                    MONTH(B2:B), 
                    DAY(B2:B)
                  ), 
                  SEQUENCE(
                    1, 
                    ROUNDUP(
                      (TODAY() - B2:B + 1) / 7
                    )
                  ) * 7
                ), 
                "yyyy-mm"
              ),
              IF(
                E2:E="Monthly",
                TEXT(
                  EDATE(
                    B2:B, 
                    SEQUENCE(
                      1, 
                      DATEDIF(B2:B, TODAY(), "M") + 1
                    )
                  ), 
                  "yyyy-mm"
                ),
                IF(
                  E2:E="Quarterly",
                  TEXT(
                    EDATE(
                      B2:B, 
                      SEQUENCE(
                        1, 
                        DATEDIF(B2:B, TODAY(), "M") / 3 + 1
                      ) * 3
                    ), 
                    "yyyy-mm"
                  ),
                  TEXT(
                    EDATE(
                      B2:B, 
                      SEQUENCE(
                        1, 
                        DATEDIF(B2:B, TODAY(), "Y") + 1
                      ) * 12
                    ), 
                    "yyyy-mm"
                  )
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      D2:D
    },
    "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2) 
     WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL 
     GROUP BY Col1 
     LABEL Col1 'Month', SUM(Col2) 'Total Amount'"
  )
)

Whereby B:B is the date, D:D is the amount and E:E is the frequency. This is outputting the months correctly, but the values don't seem to be correct. Thanks if anyone can shed some light on this or as a potential solution even if the input data layout needs to be tweaked!

Does the above output table contain the actual numbers that are derived from the given input table OR just a generalized representation of what is needed. If its the former, it would help to provide some backend logic on how April'24 is 103 & May'24 is 2109?! If its the later scenario do provide realistic output numbers so that we can tally the numbers while creating the formula.
